# String from Database set as public string

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Ok from the answer from the previous question the reasoning still applies here but this time A different issue. There is a login system (Loginvb.vb) that I got for the launcher I was creating and was wondering 2 things:

1. Is there a better way to do the Login check with the database (as in
   more secure) (the login style will have a web based registration
   setting via PHP script)?
2. Is there a way to take a certain column (labled as access) in the database and put it
   as a public string so I can check if it will equal 1 2 or 3 in a
   different form labeled as Main.vb

Here is the current login check:

```vb
Public Sub login_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles login.Click
    If txtuserName.Text = "" Or txtpassWord.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("You cannot progress until you login....(moron =p)")
    Else
        'Connects To the Database 
        Dim connect As MySqlConnection
        connect = New MySqlConnection()
        connect.ConnectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;user id=sc;Password=derp;database=sclaunch" 'not the actual login ;)
        Try
            connect.Open()
        Catch myerror As MySqlException
            MsgBox("Error Connecting to Database. Please Try again !")
        End Try
        'SQL Query To Get The Details
        Dim myAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim sqlquerry = "Select * From login where username = '" + txtuserName.Text + "' And password= '" + txtpassWord.Text + "'"
        Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand()
        'My fail attempt at what I am trying to do :(
        Dim sql22 As MySqlConnection
        sql22 = New MySqlConnection()
        sql22.ConnectionString = "Select * From login where access ="
        'End of fail attempt
        myCommand.Connection = connect
        myCommand.CommandText = sqlquerry
        'Starting The Query
        myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand
        Dim mydata As MySqlDataReader
        mydata = myCommand.ExecuteReader
        'To check the Username and password and to validate the login 
        If mydata.HasRows = 0 Then
            MsgBox("Invalid Login")
        Else
            'fail testing xD
            Label3.Text = sql22
            MsgBox("You are now Loged In!")

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Still basically learning more and more as I am coding all this got to love trial and error and the moments where you get stuck =/ (Sorry to the admins or whatever for fixing tag issues still new to the site xD)

Comment: are you trying to read the column `access` belonging at the same record of the user for which you check the password and username?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the same table `login` that contains the credentials contains also the `access` column that you want to retrieve, then I have changed a lot of your code

```
    Dim sqlquerry = "Select * From login where username = @name AND password=@pwd"
    Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand(sqlquery, connect)
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtuserName.Text)
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", txtpassWord.Text)
    Dim mydata = myCommand.ExecuteReader

    If mydata.HasRows = False Then
        MsgBox("Invalid Login")
    Else
        ' the same record that contains the credentials contains the access field'
        mydata.Read()
        Label3.Text = mydata("access").ToString()
        MsgBox("You are now Loged In!")
    End If
```

What I have changed:

- Removed the string concatenation and added the appropriate parameters
- Removed myAdapter and every references to it (not needed, you don't
  fill DataTable/DataSet)
- Removed sql22 and every references to it. It's a Connection and you
  try to use like a Command
- Fixed the check on HasRows (Returns a boolean not an integer. Are you
  using Option Strict Off?)

Comment: Well seeing the size difference of the 2 logins I feel bit stupid by over thinking everything haha For the option strict not sure if I have it on or off, just woke up to work on the login system. And yes the access is in the same column. This worked.